# Appending heredoc string after a specific heredoc string if file doesn't contain that heredoc string?

Tags: ruby

I want to append a heredoc string after a specific heredoc string if file doesn't contain it already.

Eg.

Here are 2 files:

```
# file1
Description:
  I am a coder
Username: user1
Password: password1

# file2
Description:
  I am a coder
Username: user2
Password: password2
Address:
  Email: user@gmail.com
  Street: user street 19 A
```

I want to add:

```
Address:
  Email: user@gmail.com
  Street: user street 19 A
```

if file doesn't contain it already, and after:

```
Description:
  I am a coder
```

So in the above files it will be added to the first one only. and that file will then look like this:

```
# file1
Description:
  I am a coder
Address:
  Email: user@gmail.com
  Street: user street 19 A
Username: user1
Password: password1
```

How could I do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not well formulated - you are getting the concept "Here Docs" confused.

I'll leave some code wich I hope helps in your task, in some way

```
end_of_line_delimiter = "\n"
file1_arr = File.read('file1.txt').split(end_of_line_delimiter)  #Array of lines
file1_has_address = file1_arr.index {|a_line| a_line =~ /^Address:/ }

unless file1_has_address
  #file1 does not contain "Address:"
  #Build address_txt
  email       = "some@email"
  street      = "some street"
  address_txt = <<END
Address:
  Email:  #{email}
  Street: #{street}
END
  #Insert address_txt 2 lines after the "Description:" line
  description_line_index = file1_arr.index {|a_line| a_line =~ /^Description:/ }
  raise "Trying to insert address, but 'Description:' line was not found!" unless description_line_index
  insert_line_index = description_line_index + 2
  file1_arr.insert(insert_line_index, *address_txt.split(end_of_line_delimiter))

end

#file1_arr will now have any Address needed added
file1_txt = file1_arr.join(end_of_line_delimiter) 

puts file1_txt
```

Please report back any success with the code :)